# Can not copy-paste a tweet in Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, arch-linux, twitter

It is a weird problem. I am unable to copy from or paste into a tweet in Firefox. e.g.

- I can copy some content from a web-page but can not paste it into tweets at Twitter (works in Chrome)
- If I copy some content from a tweet, then it does not appear when I paste it, just empty (works in Chrome)

I can do all of copy-paste without any problem in gmail or other web-pages in Firefox. I have cleared all the cache,  even deleted *~/.mozilla* and *~/.cache* directories by hand too but nothing helps (I use [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all cache directories (~/.mozilla and ~/.cache). Used Firefox without logging in Firefox-Sync account. Then removed all cache directories again and used it for sometime and removed cached directories 3rd time and then it started working fine.